# No such method error. The getter was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I am building simple TodoList App in flutter using **Provider Package** and **ListView.Builder**.

**TaskModel.dart**

```
class TaskModel { //Model class for the data to be stored
String task;
bool isCompleted;
String get getTask => task;
bool get getIsCompleted => isCompleted;
TaskModel({this.task, this.isCompleted});
}
```

**Tasker.dart**

```
class Tasker extends ChangeNotifier {
List<TaskModel> myTasks = [];

void addTask(TaskModel taskToAdd) {
myTasks.add(taskToAdd);
notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

Now there is *ListView.Builder* where I am trying to access the **myTasks** from **Tasker** Class.

```
Consumer<Tasker>(
                  builder: (context, newTask, child) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: newTask.myTasks.length,  //The error is when accessing newTask.myTasks
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(.....);
                        });
                  },
                ),
```

The error messge is
*

> The getter 'myTasks' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
>   myTasks

*

Comment: Where in your code do you provide the Tasker? Something like `Provider(create: (_) => Tasker(), child: ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that you miss the provider, which connect your class, because it's can't detect your model if you not defined it first

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskModel>( //      <--- ChangeNotifierProvider
      create: (context) => TaskModel(),
child:Consumer<Tasker>(
                  builder: (context, newTask, child) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: newTask.myTasks.length,  //The error is when accessing newTask.myTasks
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(.....);
                        });
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: I have used this:-                    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => Tasker(); )

Comment: Ok I came to know builder method is depricated.